# How many blocks can be cut avoiding the fracture?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, problem-solving

> The diagram shows a cubic block of marble ($1 \times 1 \times 1\ \mathrm {m^3}$) having a planar fracture. What is the maximum number of slabs sized $20 \times 20 \times 5\ \mathrm {cm^3}$ that can be cut from this block avoiding the fracture?
>
> [image]

How to solve this aptitude question? Please help me in this regard.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

It is rather difficult to demonstrate what the optimal strategy is for packing problems like this and it often results in a more trial and error approach.

Without the fracture we could of course slice the whole block in 25 smaller blocks of dimension $20 \times 20 \times 100$ cm, each containing 20 pieces and since there is no unused part the maximum number of possible plates would be $25 \times 20 = 500$.

If we align the smaller blocks along the fracture (assumed to be perfectly flat and thin), the fracture would intersect only 5 blocks on the diagonal, leaving 20 perfect smaller blocks and hence $20\times20=400$ plates.

So can we do better? This is where trial and error comes in. An "obvious" other approach would be to make big rectangular slices parallel to the fracture both thickness 5 cm. The bottom of the first slice has dimensions $100 \sqrt{2} \times 100 \times 5$ but the top is a bit smaller,i.e. $(100 \sqrt{2}-10) \times 100 \times 5$, which is big enough to fit $6 \times 5 = 30$ plates. The next slice is a bit smaller, but can also fit 30 plates. If you do the math you will find that the successive slices can contain $30,30,25,25,20,20,15,15,10,10,5,5$ plates, which gives you a total of 210 plates above the fracture and likewise 210 plates below. Together you therefore get 420 plates and hence this is better than before.
(Better also from a practical point of view, because there is a bit more space available, whereas for the other arrangement cuts would have to be perfect.)

I might be wrong of course, but I would expect that this is the best result possible. Proving this is a whole different matter.